# Curl for loop issue

Tags: shell, for-loop, curl

```
for a in {P02183606,P02183608}
do
for b in {PID,PID2}
do
curl -i -H "Authorization:Token sample" "Content-type: application/json" -X GET "http://mastindia//project/push?applicationRefNo=$a&applicationFormId=$b"
done;
done;
```

Expected Output
Service should call 2 times not 4 times.(Issue is only $a and $ b values should be below)

```
http://applicationRefNo=P02183606&applicationFormId=PID
http://applicationRefNo=P02183608&applicationFormId=PID2
```

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to post your authorization token in public. It's certainly not necessary for the question.

Answer (score 1):

A nested for loop will always run n*n2 times.

In your case, there is no need to nest the loop, you can just do it like this:

```
#bin/bash
whatever=("P02183606" "PID" "P02183608" "PID2");
for((i = 0; i<${#whatever[@]}; i=i+2));
do
curl -i -H "Authorization:Token dont share it ffs" "Content-type: application/json" -X GET "http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=${whatever[i]}&applicationFormId=${whatever[i+1]}"
echo "Accessing: http://indiafirstlife.com/onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=${whatever[i]}&applicationFormId=${whatever[i+1]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Accessing: http://indiafirstlife.com/onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=P02183606&applicationFormId=PID
Accessing: http://indiafirstlife.com/onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=P02183608&applicationFormId=PID2
```